# Does AppleCare warranty follow the device or the user?

Tags: macbook-pro, applecare

I've bought a used MacBook Air and according to the serial I've noticed that the previous owner has linked an AppleCare plan to it, up to 2017.

Does the warranty follow the device or the user? Better put, as the new owner, can I take advantage of the warranty or is there a need of some sort of transfer?

Answer (score 4):

The previous owner has to transfer it to the new owner.  See, "Is the AppleCare Protection Plan or AppleCare+ transferable?" under [AppleCare Products Frequently Asked Questions](http://www.apple.com/support/products/faqs.html), it states:

> **Is the AppleCare Protection Plan or AppleCare+ transferable?**
>
> Yes. If you choose to sell or give away your Apple product, you can
>   also transfer the ownership of the AppleCare Protection Plan or
>   AppleCare+. Please see the [Terms and Conditions](http://www.apple.com/legal/sales-support/) for complete details.

Answer (score 4):

i recently learnt that, the applecare follows the device and does not necessarily need you to transfer ownership.
But
The provide the option to transfer ownership because the original owner can cancel the applecare protection anytime and get a prorated refund of the full amount.